SFMC Mobile Connect Message Undelivered
I've been trying to troubleshoot a mobile connect subscriber not receiving our SMS messages. After some digging, SFDC Help said that the mobile number is 4505 erroring "FailedDueToInvalidDestinationAddress" and I've found that the subscriber mobile number is from textrequest.com. In my research, I've found that this shouldn't affect the deliverability. Does anyone have any insights on this?
